# Axios POST promise not working as expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, async-await, axios

I have a react/node/express app with Sequelize/mysql. Using Axios for API calls.

What I need to do:

1. POST recipe to DB
2. Wait for the above to complete
3. GET recipes table again to update the react component state with the new recipe

What currently happens:

1. recipe gets POSTed to DB
2. GET recipes gets executed before the
   promise is returned from the POST. Thus, the component state gets
   set to old data.

I tried to use async/await but this did not make a difference.

Here's the abridged code:

**API.js:**

```
addRecipe: async function(newRecipe) {
    let addRecipe = await axios.post('/api/recipes/new', newRecipe) 
    return addRecipe
},
getRecipes: function() {
    return axios.get('/api/recipes');
}
```

**Recipes.js:**

```
  import API from '../../utils/API';
  state = {
    dbRecipes: []
  }

  getRecipes = () => {
    API.getRecipes()
      .then(res => {
        this.setState({
          dbRecipes: res.data
        })
      })
  }

  handleFormSubmit = event => {
  event.preventDefault();
    API.addRecipe(formData).then(result => {
       this.getRecipes()
    })
  }
```

**addRecipe controller:**

```
exports.addRecipe = function (req, res) {
  const imgPath = req.file.path.replace('client/public','');
  db.Recipe.create({
    RecipeName: req.body.RecipeName,
    RecipeDescription: req.body.RecipeDescription,
    RecipeImage: imgPath
  }).then(function (newRecipe) {
    RecipeIngredients = JSON.parse(req.body.RecipeIngredients)
    var promises = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < RecipeIngredients.length; i++) {
      var RecipeId = newRecipe.dataValues.id;
      promises.push(
        db.RecipeAmount.create({
          Amount: RecipeIngredients[i].AmountForSmall,
          Size: 'sm',
          Type: 'smoothie',
          IngredientId: RecipeIngredients[i].IngredientId,
          RecipeId: RecipeId
        })
      );

      promises.push(
        db.RecipeAmount.create({
          Amount: RecipeIngredients[i].AmountForMedium,
          Size: 'md',
          Type: 'smoothie',
          IngredientId: RecipeIngredients[i].IngredientId,
          RecipeId: RecipeId
        })
      );

      promises.push(
        db.RecipeAmount.create({
          Amount: RecipeIngredients[i].AmountForLarge,
          Size: 'lg',
          Type: 'smoothie',
          IngredientId: RecipeIngredients[i].IngredientId,
          RecipeId: RecipeId
        })
      );
    }

    sequelize.Promise.all(promises).then(function () {
      //this does get logged out in the backend console
      console.log('DONE ADDING');
    });

  });
};
```

Comment: are you sure that your back end is properly implemented, in that the recipe data is inserted into your DB, etc, before the POST request returns a response?

Comment: @DacreDenny as far as I can tell, everything gets posted correctly. All the records are in DB, and when I refresh the page, the state also gets correctly updated. But, since you bring that up, I'll add the code for my addRecipe controller

Comment: Do you have any other similar controllers where this functions as expected?  It looks like your request handler triggers some async functions and immediately returns (ie: the request will complete prior to async functions completing)

Comment: @GeorgeChanturidze please see updated answer - does this solve your problem?

Comment: @AlexMcMillan I don't have any other examples... can you clarify exactly which parts of the code you are talking about?

Comment: Where are you sending a response in `addRecipe`?

Comment: @AndyGaskell I'm not, do I have to?? Not sure why I'd need a response. Sequelize is promise-based, I thought all I need is a promise. If I do need this then please explain why/how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the solution is to adjust your addRecipe controller by ensuring that the `res` call back is called. Seeing that your 'DONE ADDING' message is logged, we can invoke the `res` callback as follows:

```
sequelize.Promise.all(promises).then(function () {
      //this does get logged out in the backend console
      console.log('DONE ADDING');

    res.send(); // <-- call the response callback to send a response back 
           // to client only after DB has been updated
});
```

This should ensure that you're axio post on client-side only completes once the new data is in the DB. In turn this should cause the call to `API.getRecipes()` to only be invoked once the DB is updated - everything should then work as expected

Comment: how are you calling `exports.addRecipe`  in the backend?

Comment: `router.post('/recipes/new', upload.single('selectedFile'), Recipes_controllers.addRecipe);`

note, the upload part is for the file upload feature I have.

Comment: ok - what is the framework you are using for your backend? There should be a way to support async operations in your backend routes, so that you can ensure the DB has completed it's insertion before you return a result. This will be key to guarantee your code functions correctly.

Comment: I'm just using Node with Express server, MySQL db through Sequelize ORM. I have similar insertion operations for "ingredients", and it works just fine. Here I think the recipe data takes a bit longer to process before posting, so it just bugs out. I tried to setTimeout before getRecipes, and it works as a hack. Just want a proper way to do it :)

Comment: Great - my answer above is based on the assumption that you are using express routes in this way https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html - in other words, that both `req` and `res` are passed to your route handler (ie `addRecipe`), so that you can guarantee the data is inserted into your DB before a response is sent back to the client

Comment: excellent! this worked. I had to do `res.send()`. Not precisely `res()` as you first pointed out initially. But you were right all along, please update your answer and I will accept.

Comment: Ah, sorry about that - minor error on my part , please see corrected answer above